# Nreco PdfGenrator force new page

Tags: c#, html

How to force new page with HTML in NReco PdfGenerator with C#?

Maybe specific class or id, like this works for pagination:

```
<div style='height: 60px;'>Seite <span class='page'></span> von <span class='topage'></span></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Page break may be forced with the following css:

```
<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
```